# Strange Bootstrap Carousel Issue..first slide not loading initially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The bootstrap carousel is working fine after sliding to second slide...however first slide is coming empty initially..once the second slide is loaded the carousel start working fine. I'm able to navigate through all slides.

```
<div id="mediakit_carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
              <!-- Indicators -->
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#mediakit_carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#mediakit_carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#mediakit_carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#mediakit_carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#mediakit_carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
              </ol>

              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                  <img src="img/mediakit_image.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/mediakit_image.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/mediakit_image.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/mediakit_image.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="img/mediakit_image.png" alt="">
                </div>

              </div>                  
            </div>

<script>$(window).load(function() {
              $('#mediakit_carousel').carousel({

        })
  });</script>
```

The above javascript is coming from external js file.

Any ideas? anyone?

Comment: try with `$(document).ready(function() {$('#mediakit_carousel').carousel({

        })
  });`

Comment: I tried ur code...issue is still there..
It is supposed to work without script call.

Comment: your code works http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/v00t5m6a/1/ check your console if there are any errors

Comment: I tried refreshing..but for me the issue is still there..I managed to fix the issue by adding this to js file.. $('.active.item img').css("line-height",'2'); just refreshing the image on load.

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap documentation:

> The data-ride="carousel" attribute is used to mark a carousel as animating starting at page load. It cannot be used in combination with (redundant and unnecessary) explicit JavaScript initialization of the same carousel.

Then you declared your crousel by the attributes, no need for the script there.

Comment: I tried without the javascript..the issue is still there.